# How to eval list indices in a safe way?

Tags: python, list, indexing, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

I try to evaluate some Python expressions like `[1, 2, 3][1]`. I can't use `eval('[1, 2, 3][1]')` because every time I do that, a kitten might die. A safer way is to use `ast.literal_eval('[1, 2, 3][1]')`, however, it raises a ValueError:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string ...
```

What can be done in order to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "some Python expressions like [1, 2, 3][1]", what does that encompass? If it's specifically "a list literal followed by an index in square brackets", then you could break it into pieces, evaluate them with literal_eval, and then combine them in your own logic. If it's more general than that, please describe.

Comment: Yes, it's a list literal followed by an index in square brackets, a command that works using `eval([1, 2, 3][1])`. How can I break it into pieces?

Answer (score 2):

There might be some better way, but if the format is just as you describe (a list literal followed by an index literal in square brackets), then you can separate it into parts, evaluate them individually, and then combine them in your logic.

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval
string = '[1, 2, 3][1]'
m = re.match(r'^(\[.+\])\[(.+)\]$', string)
mylist = literal_eval(m.group(1))
index = literal_eval(m.group(2))
value = mylist[index]
# gives value 2
```

Comment: Ah, get it. It looks like trying to design your own way to compile this code. Might there be a better options in future Python versions, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

If it's as simple as selecting integer from list, you could parse it yourself.

```
s = "[1, 12, 30][-1]"

def foo(s):
    arr = []
    curr = ""
    for c in s:
        if c.isdigit() or c in ["-"]:
            curr += c
        elif c == "," or c == "]":
            arr.append(int(curr))
            curr = ""

    lst, ind = arr[:-1], arr[-1]
    return lst[ind]
    
foo(s)
# 30
```

Or maybe

```
arr, ind = (
    s.replace("][", ";").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ", "").split(";")
)
int(arr.split(",")[int(ind)])
```

Comment: It's an option too but seems to be a lot of hard work for this quite simple task.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely produce an AST from the input, using the `compile` built-in. But you cannot safely evaluate the AST. So you'll have to walk the AST yourself, collecting the literal integers and making a list out of them. If the expression is as simple as you say, that won't be difficult.